# Can't install gem ray

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I've tried to install gem [ray](http://mon-ouie.github.com/projects/ray.html) but I got a message (short)

```
ERROR:  Error installing ray:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

The full version of message you can see [here](https://gist.github.com/2408537)

My platform: Ubuntu 11.10 x64

How to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the key line from your gist:

```
checking for main() in -lopenal... no
```

You will need an openal library.
In ubuntu there are usually a few ways it is formatted in the package manager:

```
Sudo apt-get install openal
openal-dev
libopenal
libopenal-dev
libopenal1
```

Also as in the comments below, you might have a problem with sndfile, which should be libsndfile1-dev at the time of this edit.

---

source: http://notesofgreg.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/generic-gem-install-error-solving.html

Comment: On this command it says 'Unable to locate package openal', i've tried to google it but with no success.

Comment: not sure if that's right, but `libopenal` rings a bell. Maybe that's it?

Comment: Often formatted as "libopenal" or "openal-dev" from my experiance.
I know for sqlite3 its sqlite3-dev and libsqlite3 you need.
Check the package manager for sensible options.

Comment: I've installed openal as libopenal, but I got next problem '-lsndfile... no'. I tried to install 'sudo apt-get install libsndfile' but no luck - 'Unable to locate package libsndfile'.

Comment: Can you post how you got sndfile? Was it libsndfile or sndfile-dev? People from the future will need to know this!

Comment: I believe that it worked after I've installed libsndfile1-dev

Comment: I think the package is now called "libopenal1" - that's what I needed to install to get openal working (for another purpose). See here for reference: http://askubuntu.com/questions/122939/unable-to-locate-package-openal